# Efficiently making Cell Notes from another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm making a Google Sheet for a TTRPG I play with some friends and I'm trying to find the best way to make automated cell notes. I found a solution here that works and modified it to match my sheet but I'm VERY new to Google Scripts and am sure I'm doing things inefficiently.

Right now the solution is:

```
function onEdit(e){  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Digital');   
   var range = sheet.getRange("R31:T59");
   range.clearNote();

  for (var x=1;x<30;x++) {   
    range.getCell(x, 1).setNote(range.getCell(x, 3).getValue());  
  } 
}
```

This is a workable solution for my needs but I always want to take things farther than just "workable" :). I know a small amount of C# but JavaScript is entirely new to me. The issues I see with my current implementation and possible areas of improvement are:

1. Because of formatting requirements on another section of the sheet, every other row where I am running this solution will ALWAYS be empty, but the solution is going to check the empty rows for notes every time. Is there a way for me to have the solution skip every second row? Can I specify exact cells rather than a range (and does JavaScript use absolute references like sheet formulas)?
2. Can I specify multiple ranges within the sheet for this solution to act on? Is it as simple as defining a second range?
3. Is it possible to restrict the `onEdit(e)` function's activation to only fire when specific ranges are edited? I'm generating a list of "Talents" that need the script to run whenever a player changes their gear through a validation list but to my understanding (and testing) `onEdit(e)` is going to run when any cell is modified (which will lead to numerous unneccessary script activations).
4. If I have multiple copies of the same tab active in the same sheet is it possible for multiple players to be using their own version of the sheet at the same time? (I think this must require the removal/modification of the getSheetByName line, but I'm only 2 days into trying to learn this!)

Huge apology for having so many questions! Any and all help is deeply appreciated!

[Visual of the sheet for formatting reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmuHi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Copy of Digital") {
    var range = sheet.getRange("R31:T59");
    let notes = sheet.getRange("T31:T59").getDisplayValues()
    range.clearNote();
    sh.getRange(31,18,notes.length,notes[0].length).setNotes(notes);
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an "Undefined Variable" error that seems to be pointing at `e.range.getSheet();` -- I tried to troubleshoot it but my knowledge is beginner at best. :|

That said, I was able to combine your note logic with my existing solution and it's WAY faster than it was before, thank you so much!!! \o/